# ESLint: spacing inside parenthesis with react

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Does anyone know which ESLint configuration rule is causing my `jsx` inside parenthesis to be 4 more spaces on the left then I expect?

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.scss';

const TableWrapper = ({
    children,
}) => (
        <div className="table-wrapper">
            {children}
        </div>
    );

export default TableWrapper;
```

Using `eslint:recommended`, `plugin:react/recommended`, and `eslint-config-prettier`

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the eslint. Spaces between and so on, is your prettier. I would suggest you create a `.prettierrc` file in the root folder and play with the settings. Here is a basic example of what you can copy paste into the file

```
{
 "endOfLine": "lf",
 "semi": true,
 "singleQuote": true,
 "tabWidth": 2,
 "trailingComma": "es5",
}
```

In your case, the tabWidth will affect how much spaces there is between your parentheses

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I don't think this is prettier. I have a `. prettierrc` with `"tabWidth": 4`. My spacing everywhere else looks correct, it's just in `jsx` inside parenthesis.